# Setting up PHPmailer, not receiving any emails?

Tags: php, email

I've been trying to set up my php emailer today but for some reason it simply isn't sending my emails. I have my website hosted with hostgator and was told to set up the smtp via gator3115.hostgator.com with port 465 when using hostgator which is what i've done but when I check the recipient email there still isn't anything on there. Anyone know what's going on here?

```
<?php
    ob_clean();session_start();

    if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();  
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){   

        require 'PHP/mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'gator3115.hostgator.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = '*******';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = '*******';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->setFrom('matt@sulmaxmarketing.com', 'Mailer');
        $mail->addAddress('sulmaxcp@gmail.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
        $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
        $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
        $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
        $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

        $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
        $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
        $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'Message has been sent';
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: do you get message has been sent? or message could not be sent?with the echo statements

Comment: Check your server log and see what possible error messages have PHPMailer generated. Sometimes catching the error at the `$mail->send()` stage is insufficient to troubleshoot.

Comment: @baboizk no neither message is being displayed.

Comment: @Terry i'll check and see what they say thanks

Comment: @Terry sometimes I quickly try a different email to just make sure it's not related to the host or something. Did you try let's say gmail settings for a sec? and see if that sends?

Comment: And what Terry said follows up then. If that's not It you must see the server log for possible errors

Comment: In all honesty, there are many things that can go wrong with PHPmailer: SMTP settings, HTTPS encryption and certificates, the correct ports and mode (TLS or SSL)... I have been setting it up in several production settings, and the most useful information to troubleshoot non-working PHPmailer installations is often from the server logs ;)

Comment: @Terry cool!. More practical experience leads to better advice :D

Comment: My brain still gets scrambled by PHPmailer from time to time, tho!

Comment: @baboizk I tried the gmail method like this but got the same results...